# ColdFusion equivalent to JavaScript array slice function?

Tags: arrays, list, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm looking for some way to take the first *x* number of elements from an array (or list). Something that works similar to the `Left()` string function, or JavaScript's [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.

So that it would do something like...

```
a = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,1,9];
x = 10;
firstTen = ArrayLeft(a, x);
// ...or...
firstTen = ArraySlice(a, 1, x); 
//         ^ Returns the elements from 1 to 10: [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,6,7,8]
```

Comment: what version of ColdFusion are you on? This function was added in ColdFusion 10. If you're on CF9 or lower [this](http://www.cflib.org/udf/arraySlice) or [this](http://www.cflib.org/udf/arraySlice2) should work

Comment: @Matt -- That's a great answer. I'm using CF9 actually, and didn't check the later docs for CF10. I guess I should have googled "ArraySlice" -- I thought I was just spitballing that, but turns out that's the official name! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ColdFusion 9 you can just use the underlying Java methods to do it. Just need to remember that Java has 0 based arrays:

```
a = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,1,9];
writedump(a.subList(0,10));
```

In ColdFusion 10+ you can use ArraySlice https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySlice

```
a = [1,2,1,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,1,9];
writedump(arraySlice(a, 1, 10));
```

This time the array is 1 based (as it normally is in CFML)